# Jenkins: how do we set classpath in Groovy plugin?

Tags: unix, jenkins

I have Jenkins machine with installed curl and [groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin). 
It appears groovy plugin doesn't see `curl`:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl --help": error=2, No
>   such file or directory    at
>   hudson498415761639726388.run(hudson498415761639726388.groovy:1)

I executed shell command `whereis curl` and obtained

> /usr/bin/curl /usr/include/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz

How should I pass it to "Class path" plugins input correctly to make it work?

[image: groovy_plugin]